# Document.referrer contains given string or not

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I want to check whether a string returned by document.referrer contains desired string or not. For example: I have used document.referrer as below and used split.

```
var ref1= document.referrer.split('/');
```

But my problem is to check whether the returned string from document.referrer contains a particular string or not.
eg:

```
ref1 contains home/index.html or not.
```

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//var ref1= document.referrer;
var ref1= "http://yoursite.com/home/index.html?pp=Nav_shop&sId=340076986";

var search = "home/index.html";
if (ref1.indexOf(search) > -1)
    alert('Found');
else 
    alert('Not Found !');
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oLwLtrug/)

Comment: Does this work if there is long string after index.html? Like there may be string like http://yoursite.com/home/index.html?pp=Nav_shop&sId=340076986

Comment: you mean long query strings? provide example to clarify your question

Comment: Yes long query string. See example above

Comment: Yes of course, I have updated the ref1 string , you can test in [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/oLwLtrug/1/) with any url you want. above code seeking for whatever you put in search variable for example "home/index.html" in ref1 string.